# Jinja 2 - Value from list

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, jinja2

When I'm posting `object['userinfo']` to Jinja2 HTML, it renders this info.

```
[{  
    'enemies':[  

    ],
    'url':'URL',
    'friends':[  
        {  
            'area':2,
            'same_interest':6
        }
    ]
}]
```

So if I'm getting `object['userinfo'][0]` it will return the object:

```
{  
    'enemies':[  

    ],
    'url':'URL',
    'friends':[  
        {  
            'area':2,
            'same_interest':6
        }
    ]
}
```

But as soon as I'm trying to get the URL value from the object (`object['userinfo'][0]['url']`),
 I get an error:
`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element 0`
even though I can access the "0" element without any other key.

EDIT:
Full error traceback:

```
     [2018-05-11 17:02:30,617] ERROR in app: Exception on /start [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/flask/app.py", line 117, in startreporting
    return render_template("report.html", items=loaded_r)
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/flask/templates/report.html", line 29, in top-level template code
    <td>{{ x['userinfo'][0]['url'] }}</td>
  File "/flask/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 411, in getitem
    return obj[argument]
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element 0
127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2018 17:02:30] "POST /start HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

How can I access the keys within the first array of the object?

Comment: What is your **full** error traceback? *(I should really have a keyboard shortcut for that!)*

Comment: Added the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

it will work 100 %

**Pass this data into context variable  of flask function**

```
> user_info = [{  
>             'enemies':[  
>         
>             ],
>             'url':'URL',
>             'friends':[  
>                 {  
>                     'area':2,
>                     'same_interest':6
>                 }
>             ]
>         }]
```

use this jinja tempalte code in html file

```
{% for data in user_info %}

    {{data.enemies}} # return []
    {{data.url}} #return 'URL'

    {% for frnd in data.friends %}
     {{frnd.area}} # return 2
     {{frnd.same_interest}} #return 6
    {%endfor}


{% endfor %}
```